# I cant set up MFA in Salesforce, cant see "App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator"

Tags: mfa

I cant complete the below steps because I dont see *App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator* Is this a license issue?

From your personal settings, in the Quick Find box, enter Advanced User Details, then select Advanced User Details.
In the Quick Find box, enter Personal Information, then select Personal Information.
Find App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator, and click Connect.

Answer (score 0):

> From your personal settings, in the Quick Find box, enter Advanced User Details, then select Advanced User Details. In the Quick Find box, enter Personal Information, then select Personal Information. Find App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator, and click Connect.

You need `Advanced User Details`, not `Personal Information`.

So the instruction will look like:

> From your personal settings, in the Quick Find box, enter Advanced User Details, then select Advanced User Details. Find App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator, and click Connect.

App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator will be there.

[image]

[image]